# pictures in a table changed with a button

Tags: html

If I have pictures in a table and I want the pictures to be changed by a button how would I do that, and still keep  my table?. For example I have a picture of a bear and I want to change it to a cat by pressing change button. I'm trying to make it like a traffic light sequence from bear to cat to dog. Using HTML

Comment: How many images in the table ? is there one button for each image ?

Comment: There are 3 images in the table

Comment: There's on button for the whole table to go from bear, to cat, to dog

Answer (score 3):

### With one change...

**html**

```
<img id="image" src="imageOfBear.jpg" />
<button type="button" onclick="changeImage()">Show cat!</button>
```

**javascript**

```
function changeImage () {
   document.getElementById("image").src = "imageOfCat.jpg";
}
```

### With more images...

**html**

```
<img id="image" src="imageOfDog.jpg" />
<button type="button" onclick="changeImage()">Show cat!</button>
```

**javascript**

```
var listOfImages = ["imageOfBear.jpg","imageOfCat.jpg","imageOfDog.jpg"];
var index = 0;

function changeIndex () {
   index += 1;
   if (index=>listOfImages.length) {
     index = 0;
   }
}

function changeImage () {
   document.getElementById("image").src = listOfImages[index];
   changeIndex();
}
```

Comment: The use of jquery here was unannounced and unnecessary.

Comment: true, I edited without jquery ;)

Comment: This is much better!

Comment: I'm not great at html or jquery (I had to search that up) I'm just trying something new.

Comment: in my opinion this is the easer way @Isabellaj ... If you need more elements you can add a list an a index

Comment: I edited the solutions with more images if you want to implement

Answer (score 1):

Give your image an id, then set an onclick event on the button and use javascript to change your pic's src property like that:

```
document.getElementById("myImg").src = "newimg.jpg";
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
var myButton = document.querySelector('.my-button'),
myImg = document.querySelector('.my-img'),
oldSrc = myImg.src,
newSrc = 'https://encrypted-tbn2.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcTIADBperxoJrqLPkRPxJDQLr4cW__6d8vUGbV6SgGoBqNpANii',
changeImg = function(){
myImg.src == oldSrc ? myImg.src = newSrc : myImg.src = oldSrc;
};
myButton.addEventListener('click', changeImg, false);
```

```css
.img-cont {
height:200px;
Width:300px;
  overflow:hidden;
}
.my-img {
Display:block;
Height:100%;}
```

```html
<div class="img-cont">
  <img class="my-img" src="http://www.nwf.org/~/media/Content/NWM/Animals/Mammals/brown-bear-cub-waving-Kevin-Dietrich-570x375.ashx">
</div>
<button class="my-button">push me</button>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/09kLkzrq/